# ionic2: can't run app in iphone because of cors origin error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm using `ionic2` i have a problem when running app in iphone, the problem is  `Response with status: 0 for URL: null` when loading data from web service, I know that it is related to `cors origin` but I append it to headers with each api call, this is an example:

```
getAllPosts(token) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return this.http.get(this.allPostsUrl+token, {headers:headers})
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
}
```

I configured it in `config.xml` file:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
```

but I still have the same problem what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: On the server side, you need to accept Access-Control-Allow-Origin... What framework are you using on the server side? I resolved the same issue, I am using Java-Spring-boot framework.

Comment: @RohanJMohite i can't understand what you mean I only uses above code to get data from api web service but i don't know where and why to use server side framework ??

Comment: Yes, I can see you are getting data from web service, Is that web service developed by you? On the web service, you need to enable  Access-Control-Allow-Origin * rather than in client side.

Comment: @RohanJMohite yes I understand You I'll do that thank you